# Embed a specific thread feed from a specific group in yammer

Tags: embed, yammer

I'm very new to yammer.

Is there any way to embed a feed from a specific thread....?

I already tried the following:

```
yam.connect.embedFeed(
 { container: "#embedded-feed", 
   network: "xxxx.com", 
   feedType: "group", 
   feedId: "xxxx", 
   config: { header: false, 
             footer: false, 
             promptText: "Comment on this" 
           } 
 });
```

If you can give references or samples it will be a great help....

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you've tried?  A code sample would be helpful.

Comment: I have tried follwing  
 yam.connect.embedFeed({
            container: "#embedded-feed",
            network: "xxxx.com",
            feedType: "group",
            feedId: "xxxx",
            config: {
                header: false,
                footer: false,
                promptText: "Comment on this"
            }
        }); this give feed for the whole group...all the threads in the group... but i want to get the feed for only a specified thread by thread id... ican get the thread id as well